# How does global and local path finding work in ROS?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there some good resource about how ROS implemented global and local path finding? If I want add some extra sensors which will have the local path finding, what is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273783/how-does-global-and-local-path-finding-work-in-ros?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi rozoalex,

You can find an overview of how the ROS navigation stack works here: http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core?distro=lunar

Details of the local planner here: http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner?distro=lunar

Details of the global planner here: http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner?distro=lunar

This is the basic scheme:

[image description http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=move_base_interfaces.png](http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=move_base_interfaces.png)

As you can see, both the local planner and the global planner use a [costmap](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d?distro=lunar) (a 2D o 3D representation of free/occupied space) constructed using sensor information.

If you want to add information from new sensors for the local costmap to consider you should do so by adding new layers to the local costmap. The layer type will depend on the sensor type. You should check the tutorials and documentation of the costmap_2d package.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on 2017-10-26**:
Thank you so much! Very helpful!